# How can I pass parameters to URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, redirect

I'm working on geolocation api which gives me CountryCode. I want to pass this country code to another api displaying images.

```
<img src="http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/flag/{country_code}.png">
```

The image interpreted by browser is

```
http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/flag/%7Bcode%7D.png
```

instead of

```
http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/flag/US.png
```

How can I fix this? What could be the possible problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

You are providing/specifying a string literal.

## Solution

Use [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
<img src={`http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/flag/${country_code}.png`} />
```

```js
const country_code = "US";

console.log(`http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/flag/${country_code}.png`);
```